# Push notification message not received in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, asmx

I am using push notification in my iOS app.

I cant able to get the push notification message from the server. But i can get the message when using third party server APN Tester free.

In my app i am using backend as .net webservice (i.e asmx file). Below are the code i am using for push notification.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

return YES;
}
/-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];

NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken");

NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceTokenString);

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:deviceTokenString
                                                message:@"devicetoken"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

/
}*/
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
_token_data =deviceToken;


NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_token_data];
NSString *trimmedString = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString:@""];
trimmedString = [trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString:@""];
trimmedString = [trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString:@""];

_tokenkey = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http:/
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<AddAppleDeviceToken xmlns=\"http:/
                        "<PortalId>0</PortalId>\n"
                        "<ModuleId>12</ModuleId>\n"
                        "<strDeviceToken>sdfssdfs</strDeviceToken>\n"
                        "</AddAppleDeviceToken>\n"
                        "</soap:Body>\n"
                        "</soap:Envelope>\n"];

NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/push.asmx"

wsDeviceToken.asmx"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[soapFormat length]];
[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue:@"http:/
[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
/
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
NSLog(@"soapFormat %@",soapFormat);
if (connect) {
    _webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Connection Establish");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"No Connection established");
}

NSString * test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Device token is %@", trimmedString];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:test
                                                message:@"devicetoken"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application     didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
if (notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
    NSLog(@"didRegisterUser");
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    UIAlertView *alert33 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"didRegisterUser"
                                                      message:@"didRegisterUser"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert33 show];
}
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
 {
NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
/
/
NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                     objectForKey:@"alert"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@""
                      message:message
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
/
}
#pragma - NSURLConnection delegate method
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
[_webData setLength: 0];
NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse;
httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
NSLog(@"HTTP error %zd", (ssize_t) httpResponse.statusCode);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
 [_webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{ NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %lu", (unsigned long)[_webData length]);
self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:_webData];
[self.xmlParser setDelegate: self];
[self.xmlParser parse];
 }
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {
}
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AddAppleDeviceTokenResult"]) {
    NSString *tmpstr = [[NSString alloc] init];
    tmpstr = [tmpstr stringByAppendingString:soapResults];
    [soapResults setString:@""];
    NSLog(@"AddAppleDeviceTokenResult %@",tmpstr);

    if([tmpstr isEqualToString:@"DeviceToken Added in Database"])
    {

        NSString * test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Device token is added in database"];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:test
                                                        message:_tokenkey
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Token added successfully");

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"1" forKey:@"isDeviceTokenAdded"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    }
}
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if (!soapResults) {
    /
    soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"soapResults %@",soapResults);
}
if([string length] > 0){
    NSString *cleanString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if([cleanString length] >0){
        [soapResults appendString: string];
    }
}
}
```

Any suggessions Please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see where you have added the delegate methods didReceiveRemoteNotification and didReceiveRemoteNotification:completionHandler ?

Comment: Are you using the Apple production or development push server?

Comment: thanks, we are using development push server...

Comment: Hi,

I have added didReceiveRemoteNotification function...
But i dont know where and how to add didReceiveRemoteNotification:completionHandler this function.. can you please supply source code for this..

Answer (score 0):

**jejai** Replace This Method

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
         NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                         objectForKey:@"alert"];
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@""
                          message:message
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

TO

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler
{

     NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]
                     objectForKey:@"alert"];
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@""
                      message:message
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```